# Poner valor por defecto en los parámetros de una función que reciba diccionarios

Tags: python, python-3.x

Me preguntaba si, ¿hay alguna manera de poner valor por defecto en los parámetros de una función que reciba diccionarios? Es decir, quiero que al llamar una función la cual le quiero pasar un clave y valor, que pueda solo pasarle clave, y que me un  valor por defecto.
Gracias.
Este seria mi código de ejemplo al cual querría modificar para hacer lo que quiero.

```
def test(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)


test(hola=10)
```

Comment: Dices en el título que la función "reciba diccionarios", pero el ejemplo de invocación que pones no recibe un diccionario, sino un entero (a través de un parámetro con nombre) ¿te refieres a esto?  Por otro lado, no entiendo bien qué pretendes. ¿Cómo se invocaría a esa función en caso de que pudiera llegar a programarse? `test(hola)`? Obviamente eso significa otra cosa (le estarías pasando como parámetro posicional el valor de una variable `hola`) ¿Quizás entonces `test("hola")`? ¿O quizás `test()` sin más, e internamente se definiría `hola` con un valor por defecto?

Comment: Por otro lado, igual era más conveniente que explicaras para qué quieres implementar esa funcionalidad. Es posible que lo que necesitas se pueda hacer de otra forma.

Comment: @abulafia Solo intentaba simular un enum de c# en python por curiosidad a como se haría

Comment: Ya me temía yo que esto era un problema XY :-) Python tiene el tipo [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), pero no veo que tenga nada qué ver con lo que has preguntado. En qué sentido se le pasa un diccionario a la función?

Comment: Voy a eliminar mi respuesta, ya que estuve leyendo sobre ese comando y no se parece en nada a lo que preguntas mi respuesta.

Comment: Lo que tendrías que usar si quieres simular un enum sería hacer un class, no una función.